# updating ancient react stack - Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm updating a long-departed colleague's React project, moving it from node 2/react 0.13/babel 5 to something *slightly* more modern with node 10/react 16/babel 7. I am relatively inexperienced with React. I am attempting to do this in a minimalist fashion, as the budget is tiny. After updating all of the libraries and dependencies to close security holes, I updated code piece by piece to correct resulting errors in the code - but I have arrived at one that is a bit inscrutable.

`ReactDOM.render(<Interface />, document.getElementById('main'));`

*Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.*

My understanding here is that the Interface component is of the wrong type (`typeof` shows it as a function). However, Interface is a component made up of a bunch of other components, so I don't know at what level the problem lies.

**frontend.js**

```
"use strict";

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Interface = require('./Interface.jsx');

ReactDOM.render(<Interface />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

**Interface.jsx**

```
/* jslint node: true, esnext: true, browser: true */
'use strict';

require('@babel/polyfill');
var React = require('react'), { Row, Alert } = require('react-bootstrap'), io = require('socket.io-client'), _ = require('lodash'), createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var Submitter = require('./Submitter.jsx'),
    Destination = require('./Destination.jsx'),
    Options = require('./Options.jsx'),
    Trace = require('./Trace.jsx'),
    Finished = require('./Finished.jsx'),
    DefaultOptions = require('../../lib/default-options.js');

var socket = io();

module.exports = createReactClass({
  connected: function() {
    console.log('connected');
    this.setState({disconnected: false});
  },
  ack: function() {
    this.state.ack = new Date().getTime();
    if (this.state.disconnected) {
      this.setState({disconnected: false});
    }
  },
  stale: function(g) {
    this.setState({stale: true});
    clearInterval(this.state.ackInterval);
  },
  preferences: function(prefs) {
    let options = _.assign({}, this.state.options, {submitter: prefs.submitter, postal_code: prefs.postal_code});
    this.setState({options});
  },
  geoip: function(geoip) {
    let options = _.assign({}, this.state.options, {geoip});
    this.setState({options});
  },
  trsets: function(trsets) {
    this.setState(...this.state, {trsets});
  },
  disconnected: function() {
    console.log('disconnect');
  },
  update: function(incoming) {
    let { type, message, content } = incoming, messages = [...this.state.messages];
    // program information
    if (content) {
      if (content.status) {
        this.state.currentStatus = content.status;
        this.state.statusMessage = message;
        this.state.progress = incoming.content;
      }
      if (content.submitted) {
        this.state.submitted = content.submitted;
      }
    }
    messages.push({ date: new Date(), type, message, content });
    this.setState(...this.state, {messages});
  },
  submitTrace: function(options) {
    this.state.currentStatus = null;
    socket.emit('submitTrace', options);
  },
  cancelTrace: function() {
    socket.emit('cancelTrace');
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    socket.on('update', this.update);
    socket.on('trsets', this.trsets);
    socket.on('connect', this.connected);
    socket.on('pong', this.ack);
    socket.on('stale', this.stale);
    socket.on('disconnect', this.disconnected);
    socket.on('preferences', this.preferences);
    socket.on('geoip', this.geoip);

    let gen = new Date().getTime();
    this.state.ackInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.state.ack) {
        if (new Date().getTime() - this.state.ack > 20000) {
          this.setState({disconnected: true});
        }
      }
      socket.emit('ping', gen, this.state.ack > 0);
    }, 500);
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      options: DefaultOptions(),
      messages: [],
      step: 'Submitter',
      currentStatus: null,
      statusMessage: null,
      trsets: null,
      ack: 0,
      lastPage: 'Submitter',
      submitted : 0
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    let message;
    if (this.state.stale) {
      message = (
        <Alert bsStyle='danger'>
          <h1>Stale client</h1>
          <p>This window should be closed since an active window is open. Check your other browser windows or refresh this window.</p>
       </Alert>
      );
    } else if (this.state.disconnected) {
      message = (
        <Alert bsStyle='danger'>
          <h1>Server disconnected</h1>
          <p>The server is not responding to ping requests. It may be necessary to restart it.</p>
       </Alert>
      );
    }
    let step;

    switch (this.state.step) {
    case 'Destination':
      step = <Destination caller={this} options={this.state.options} trsets={this.state.trsets}/>;
      break;
    case 'Options':
      step = <Options caller={this} defaultOptions={DefaultOptions()} options={this.state.options}/>;
      break;
    case 'Trace':
      step = <Trace caller={this} currentStatus={this.state.currentStatus} statusMessage={this.state.statusMessage} messages={this.state.messages} options={this.state.options} progress={this.state.progress} />;
      break;
    case 'Finished':
      step = <Finished submitted={this.state.submitted} caller={this} lastPage={this.state.lastPage} />
      break;
    default:
      step = <Submitter caller={this} options={this.state.options} />;
    }

    return (
      <div className="container">
        {message}
        <Row className="col-md-12">
          <form className='form-horizontal'>
            {step}
          </form>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  },
  stepCall: function(to, opts, fields) {
    if (fields) {
      fields.forEach(i => {
        this.state.options[i] = opts[i];
      });
    } else if (to === 'Finished') {
      this.state.lastPage = opts;
    }
    // don't default to these anymore
    delete this.state.options.geoip;

    this.setState({
      step: to
    });
    if (to === 'Trace') {
      this.submitTrace(this.state.options);
    }
  },
  savePrefs: function(prefs) {
    socket.emit('savePreferences', prefs);
  }
});
```

**Submitter.jsx**

```
/* jslint node: true, esnext: true */

var React = require('react'), {Input, Button, Panel} = require('react-bootstrap'),
    createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

module.exports = createReactClass({
  fields : ['submitter', 'city', 'postal_code', 'isp'],
  render: function() {
    var {caller} = this.props, {submitter, city, postal_code, isp, geoip} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

        <p>To get started, please provide your name, or pseudonym if you prefer. This is not required, but will help you find your own traceroutes later:
        <input type='text' placeholder='Name or pseudonym (25 chars max)' onChange={this.change.bind(null, 'submitter')} value={submitter} className='input submitter' /></p>
        <p>You appear to be near
        <input type='text' placeholder='city' onChange={this.change.bind(null, 'city')} value={city} className='input city' />
        <input type='text' placeholder='postal_code' onChange={this.change.bind(null, 'postal_code')} value={postal_code} className='input postal_code'  /> <br />
        with
        <input type='text' placeholder='Internet Service Provider' onChange={this.change.bind(null, 'isp')} value={isp} className='input isp' />
        as your internet service provider (ISP).</p>
        <p>Please correct these if appropriate. This too is optional, but will assist in more accurately positioning the origin of the traceroutes you contribute.</p>
        <Input ref='savePrefs' className='text-right' defaultChecked={true} type='checkbox' label='Store this information on your computer' />
        <Button bsStyle='primary' className='pull-right' onClick={this.use}>Continue</Button>
        <Button className='pull-right' onClick={this.cancel}>Cancel</Button>
      </div>
    );
  },
  change: function(field, e) {
    this.setState({[field]: e.target.value});
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return this.optionsWithGeoip(this.props.options, this.props.geoip);
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps(p) {
    this.setState(this.optionsWithGeoip(p.options, p.geoip));
  },
  use: function() {
    let options = {};
    this.fields.forEach(i => {
      options[i] = this.state[i];
    });

    if (this.refs.savePrefs.getChecked()) {
      this.props.caller.savePrefs(options);
    }

    this.props.caller.stepCall('Destination', options, this.fields);
  },
  cancel: function() {
    this.props.caller.stepCall('Finished', 'Submitter');
  },
  optionsWithGeoip: function(options) {
    let geoip = options.geoip || {};
    return {
      submitter: options.submitter,
      city: options.city || geoip.city,
      postal_code: options.postal_code || geoip.postal_code,
      isp: options.isp || geoip.isp
    }
  }
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "webpack-production": "webpack -p --config production.config.js",
    "webpack": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --config dev.config.js --port 2050",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development node server.js",
    "public": "NODE_ENV=public node server.js",
    "publicdev": "NODE_ENV=publicdev node server.js",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "node test/*/*",
    "build-macos": "pkg -t node10-macos-x64 server.js -o dist/macos/app --config package.json"
  },
  "pkg": {
    "scripts": "lib/*.js",
    "assets": "web/**/*"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "internet mapping tool personal data traceroute surveillance"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "async": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "cheerio": "^0.22.0",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lodash.template": "^4.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.2.1",
    "open": "^7.0.0",
    "raw-socket": "^1.7.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.33.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-less": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.7.1",
    "gulp-streamify": "1.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "http-proxy": "^1.18.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.18",
    "tape": "^4.11.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "watchify": "^3.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I just wonder if you shouldn't save whole class first, e.g. `var Interface = createReactClass({ ... })` and then `module.exports = Interface;`

Comment: I have tried that - fiddling around with exporting it like that, exporting it as a default, different types of imports (vs requires). I get the same result, with the only difference occasionally being the value of typeof in the console

Comment: Anyways I dont get something, you are using babel, why dont you just use normal ES6 Classes and import/export?

Comment: Someone else wrote 99.9% of this code, and it was written before import was really a thing. I'd have a lot of code to go through to try out this kind of change (since I'd assume I'd want it to be consistent throughout the codebase). Could be worth it, but only if we can be pretty sure it will solve the problem...

Comment: What does `./Submitter.jsx` look like?

Comment: Second attempt - `export default createReactClass({` and inside `frontend.js` - `import Interface from './Interface';`

Comment: I've added Submitter.jsx above, thx

@kind user - I gave that a go, same issue. The only thing that I can get to change is the type of the Interface - I can get Function, Module, or undefined

Comment: @cdmccann Looking through `./Submitter.jsx`, I'm noticing that `<Input />` is not a valid component from the `react-bootstrap` package. I'm not familiar with that library but the last time I worked with bootstrap, in order to have an input, you'd use a .form-control class (<FormControl /> in your react-bootstrap version). Basically you're getting that error because that component doesn't exist and you're trying to render something that doesn't exist, hence this part of the error `but got: undefined`.

Comment: @cdmccann after looking a little further in to the package, you may want to use `<Checkbox />` instead of `<Input />` or `<FormControl />` inside of `./Submitter.jsx`

Comment: @DennisMartinez - I think you nailed it! Input must have been deprecated at some point. Removing that element resolved the error. I will dig into the Checkbox component docs and figure out how to add that instead. If you want to post the above comments as an answer, I'll mark it as correct, thanks.

One other thing - I had a suspicion that the problem lay 'deeper' than Interface.jsx, but I had no way to determine that. What are the debugging practices that I could use to come to the conclusion that you came to? Thanks again...